# Oracle http server vs apache http server 2.4

Tags: java, apache, weblogic, cluster-computing

I need to know if ohs is slower then apache server and if on cluster env those two server can have different performance on request and response

Thanks you

Comment: It works best if you try your performance tests then post for reviewing

Answer (score 0):

The web server software should not have any noticeable impact on the performance giving that they are running on identical machines, the real impact is caused by the amount of traffic that is using whatever service that you are providing and the way that you implement your service. the only issue is when you try to run long query inside your service. otherwise you should be ok using any solution.